# Julia truncate inner dimension of array of arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

Given an array of arrays

`x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]]`,

what is the clean & efficient way to truncate each of the inner arrays such that I end up with

`[[1, 2], [4, 5]]`?

Is there anything as simple as `x[:,1:2]` like for multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [broadcast](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Broadcast.broadcast) `getindex`:

```
julia> x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

julia> getindex.(x, (1:2,))
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [5, 6]
```

It seems to be a bit faster than using `map`:

```
julia> foo(xs) = getindex.(xs, (1:2,))
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar(xs) = map(x -> x[1:2], xs)
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime foo($([rand(1000) for _ in 1:1000]));
  55.558 μs (1001 allocations: 101.69 KiB)

julia> @btime bar($([rand(1000) for _ in 1:1000]));
  58.841 μs (1002 allocations: 101.70 KiB)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with mutating the input vectors, then this is a very efficient way of doing it:

```
resize!.(x, 2)
```

This mutates `x` in place, so you don't need to assign an output variable.

You can also use `view`. That doesn't mutate the input, but neither does it allocate a new vector. It's faster than the broadcasted `getindex`, but not as fast as `resize!`:

```
xv = view.(x, Ref(1:2))
```

Comment: Could you explain the usage of `Ref` here?

Comment: You want to broadcast only over the elements of `x`, and not over `1:2`. The `Ref` makes it behave like a scalar.

Comment: Ah I see, so it serves the same function as David Varela putting it in a tuple?

Comment: Yes, there is only a subtle difference that isn't important here.